# Access Denied error in MVC System.Management.Automation powershell execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, exchange-server

I am currently attempting to create a user in an ASP.NET MVC application using the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command with a remote Runspace using Kerberos authentication with a service account. Currently when I attempt to execute the command on the development server the command executes successfully, however when attempting to execute the command on the live web server I receive the following message

*“Connecting to remote server echange-server failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting”*

On both the live and debug server I can enter a remote PowerShell session with Enter-PSSession. I feel as if this is a Kerberos hop issue on the live server. But I’m unsure of what SPNs would need to be configured for Kerberos to work properly for powershell. Thank you.

Comment: Is your web.config set to use the highest trust? `<system.web><trust level="Full" />`

Comment: I added this and attempted it again still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that remote powershell isn´t enabled for the taskuser you are using, which will explain the "Access is denied.". Try to enable that via (as written in the MS documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298084(v=exchg.141).aspx)) via:

```
set-user <your user account> -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True
```

Another useful source to troubleshoot your issue is the MS documentation [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/02/04/troubleshooting-exchange-2010-management-tools-startup-issues/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did this, I also checked the user to make sure the RemotePowerShell was enabled. It was and I'm still running into the same issue.